# Unable to exit with ^C

Tags: python, terminal, pytest

I am using pytest to run tests and, during the execution of a test, interrupted with ctrl-C.

No matter how many times I ctrl-C to get out of the test session (I've also tried ctrl-D to get out of the environment I'm using), my terminal prompt does not return.

I accidentally pressed F as well... `test.py ^CF^C` Does the F have something to do with my being stuck in the captured stderr section and the prompt not returning?

Are there any logic explanations why I'm stuck here, and if so, are there any alternatives to exiting this state without closing the window and force exiting the session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest trying control-Z.  That should suspend it; you can then do kill %1 (or kill -9 %1) to kill it (assuming you don't have anything else running in the background)

What I'm guessing is happening (from personal experience) is that one of your tests is running in a try / except that is catching all exceptions (including the keyboard interrupt which control c triggers) and is inside a while loop / ignoring the exception.

Comment: (By personal experience, I mean python in general; haven't seen the behavior you've described with pytest specifically)

Comment: for what it's worth, never use -9, try -15, -2, and then -1.  These signals are meant to give the errant binary a chance to clean up after itself before being killed.  If you don't know in what ways your process needs to clean up after itself, chances are you don't want it to go without. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process

Comment: Going to have to disagree... to quote noted software developer Marge Simpson when asked "Do you want the job done right or do you want it done fast?", "Well, like all Americans... fast!"  (And in all seriousness, the size of the set of one-off python programs I've written for which control-c and kill -15 (aka default kill) don't work and anything other than SIGKILL does is pretty darn near zero... and don't get me started on the awesomeness of SIGKILL not working due to NFS braindamage. )